# Showing errors in the modal rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very frustrated because I've been working on it for days and I haven't found a solution yet.

I have a Visit.rb model and, beyond the common validations, I have two more validations through two methods of mine (visit's start date cannot be prior to end one and there's no possibility to have two visits having the same start date, end date and visitor_id).

I need to show these errors set by me in the modal I'm giving to register a visit, but until now I've never had success.
In fact every time this error occurs: *ArgumentError in VisitsController#create - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty*

Here what I've done until now is...

**Visit.rb**

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to          :employee
    belongs_to          :visitor
    default_scope   ->  { order(:created_at) }

    validates   :from,          presence: true,     uniqueness: { scope: [:to, :visitor_id] }
    validates   :to,            presence: true
    validates   :visitor_id,    presence: true
    validates   :employee_id,   presence: true
    validate    :valid_date_range_required
    validate    :visit_uniqueness


    def valid_date_range_required
        if (from && to) && (to < from)
            errors[:base] << "Visit's end date cannot be prior to the start one."
        end
    end


    def visit_uniqueness
        if Visit.find_by(from: :from, to: :to, visitor_id: :visitor_id)
            errors[:base] << "A visit with the same start date, end date and visitor already exists."
        end
    end

end
```

**visits_controller.rb**

```
class VisitsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_employee,  only: [:create,    :destroy]
    before_action :correct_employee,    only: [:destroy,   :update ]

    def create
        @visit = current_employee.visits.build(visit_params)
        if @visit.save
            flash[:success] = "Visit added"
            redirect_to employee_path(session[:employee_id], :act => 'guestsVisits')
        else
            @visits = current_employee.visits.all
            @employee = current_employee
            render 'employees/guestsVisits'
        end
    end



    private

        def visit_params
            params.require(:visit).permit(:from, :to, :visitor_id, :employee_id)
        end

        def correct_employee
            @visit = current_employee.visits.find_by(id: params[:id])
            redirect_to root_url if @visit.nil?
        end
end
```

**guestsVisits.rb** (my view)

```
<div class="jumbotron3 text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Guests Visits</h1>
    <hr>
    <%=render :partial =>"layouts/sidebar"%>
    <div class="panel3">
        <div class="panel-body">

                                                    <!-- Modal for Visit -->
                <% if logged_in? %>
                <%=render :partial =>"shared/error_messages"%>

                <a class="btn icon-btn btn-success pos" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#visitModal">
                <span class="glyphicon btn-glyphicon glyphicon-plus img-circle text-success"></span>
                Add a visit
                </a>

                <div id="visitModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                        <div class="modal-content">

                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Visit</h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <%= form_for(@visit) do |f| %>

                                    <%= f.label :start_date %>
                                    <%= f.date_field :from, class: 'form-control',:value => (f.object.from.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if f.object.from) %>
                                    <%= errors_for @visit, :from %><%if @visit.errors.any?%><br><%end%>

                                    <br>
                                    <%= f.label :end_date %>
                                    <%= f.date_field :to, class: 'form-control',:value => (f.object.to.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if f.object.to) %>
                                    <%= errors_for @visit, :to %><%if @visit.errors.any?%><br><%end%>

                                    <br>
                                    <%= f.label :Visitor %>
                                    <%= f.collection_select :visitor_id, Visitor.all, :id, :full_name, { :class=> "form-control", :include_blank => ''}%>
                                    <%= errors_for @visit, :visitor_id %><%if @visit.errors.any?%><br><%end%>
                                    <br>
                                    <%= f.submit "Add visit", class: "btn btn-primary btn-color" %>
                                <% end %>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use two different versions of error_messages.rb

**error_messages.rb (1)**

```
<% if @visit && @visit.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@visit.errors.count, "error") %>.Open the modal for more details
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**error_messages.rb (2)**

```
<% if @visit.errors.any? %>
    <ul class="errors">
    <% @visit.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

I hope someone can help me because I don't understand how to figure it out.
Thank you a lot.

**EDIT:**

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  before_create :confirmation_token

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  has_many :macaddresss,    dependent:      :destroy
  has_many :visits,         dependent:      :destroy
  has_many :visitors,       dependent:      :destroy

  #Validations
  validates :name,  presence: true , length: { maximum:20 , minimum: 2 }
  validates :lastname,  presence: true, length: { maximum:20 , minimum: 2 }
  validates :gender,  presence: true
  validates :dateofbirth,  presence: true
  validates :birth_country,  presence: true
  validates :birth_place,  presence: true, length: { maximum:60}
  validates :contry_of_residence,  presence: true
  validates :city_of_residence,  presence: true, length: { maximum:60 }
  validates :address,  presence: true, length: { maximum:60 , minimum: 7 }
  validates :email,  presence: true, length: { maximum:243 } ,format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: { message: 'accept terms and conditions' }

  [...]

  has_secure_password

  def Employee.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end
end
```

**session_helper.rb**

```
  def current_employee
    @current_employee ||= Employee.find_by(id: session[:employee_id])
  end
```

**EDIT2:**

**employees_controller.rb**

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

    def show

        if logged_in?
            @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
            @indirizzimac = current_employee.indirizzimacs.new
            @visitor = current_employee.visitors.new
            @visit = current_employee.visits.new
            @visits = current_employee.visits.all
            if params[:act]=='myData'
                render 'myData'
            elsif params[:act]=='myNetwork'
                    render 'myData'
            elsif params[:act]=='temporaryUsers'
                render 'temporaryUsers'
            elsif params[:act]=='guestsVisits'
                render 'guestsVisits'
            elsif params[:act]=='myAccount'
                render 'myAccount'
            else
                render 'show'
            end
        else
            render 'static_pages/errorPage'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you try to restart dev server. The code looks ok.

Comment: Can you upload implementation of current_employee or its model

Comment: @Emmanuel Mtali added!

Answer (score 1):

From what i can see if creating visit fails you instantiate `@visits` and `@employee` instance variables  then rendering 'employees/guestsVisits' its view you use `@visit` which i think it doesn't exist inside empleyees controller
So add it ad

```
def guestsVisits
  @visit = current_employee.visits.build
end
```

Comment: I am finding a way to pass the @visit from VisitsController#create to EmployeesController#guestVisits

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help! I tried but unfortunately it didn't work. I added even the important part of employees_controller so you can understand more easily what I'm doing.

Comment: Ok! If your still stuck you can upload it to GitHub and add me as contributor "Mtali" I have nothing to do so far,  it will be my pleasure to help